# rounded Image has black square around it

Tags: android, imageview, android-imageview

i have a rectangular image that i convert to a circle, then i set that image to the imageview. however i get a black square around the circular image. I need it to match the rest of the layout which is white.Can anyone explain why?
the layout below is part of a much larger layout that is used as the layout for the listview. I tried this code alone in a different app and it worked fine. The default color of the xml layout was white in that app so maybe it is still drawing the square but i just cant see it? The default color of the xml in my original app is black. could that be causing the problem?

here is part of the layout

```
   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#fff"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_profile"
            android:layout_width="90dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please post a screenshot and some of your codes

Comment: Post your layout and post your XML file if you set as Background to your Imageview

Answer (score 0):

use this class

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.Bitmap.Config;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.graphics.PorterDuff.Mode;
import android.graphics.PorterDuffXfermode;
import android.graphics.Rect;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class RoundedCustomImageView extends ImageView{

    public RoundedCustomImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public RoundedCustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public RoundedCustomImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        Drawable drawable = getDrawable();
        if (drawable == null) {
            return;
        }
        if (getWidth() == 0 || getHeight() == 0) {
            return; 
        }

        try {
            Bitmap b = ((BitmapDrawable) drawable).getBitmap();
            Bitmap bitmap = b.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
            int w = getWidth(), h = getHeight();
            Bitmap roundBitmap =  getCroppedBitmap(bitmap, w);
            canvas.drawBitmap(roundBitmap, 0,0, null);
        } catch (OutOfMemoryError e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Bitmap getCroppedBitmap(Bitmap bmp, int radius) {
        Bitmap sbmp;
        if(bmp.getWidth() != radius || bmp.getHeight() != radius)
            sbmp = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, radius, radius, false);
        else
            sbmp = bmp;
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(sbmp.getWidth(),sbmp.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        //Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(200,200, Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);
        final int color = 0xffa19774;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, sbmp.getWidth(), sbmp.getHeight());
        //      final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, 200, 200);
        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        paint.setFilterBitmap(true);
        paint.setDither(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#030302"));
        canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
                sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(sbmp, rect, rect, paint);
        return output;
    }}
```